# How do I loop through a column containing geo-coordinate text and extract latitude and longitude, and append as separate columns?

Tags: python, string, split, nlp, geolocation

I have some data from CDC in csv format which includes geo-coordinates in a single text column as follows.  The name of the (Pandas) DataFrame is 'geotest':

```
# My original data from CDC:
geotest.head(2)

RiskFactor  GeoLocation
Smoking     (44.9033791, -122.9017427)
Alcohol     (38.84054, -97.6097)
```

What I would like to do is extract the latitude and longitudinal coordinates and append them to separate columns to my original dataset as follows:

```
# How I would like my data to look like:  Original + two new columns appended:
RiskFactor  GeoLocation                  Latitude    Longitude
Smoking     (44.9033791, -122.9017427)   44.9033791  -122.9017427
Alcohol     (38.84054,   -97.6097)       38.84054    -97.6097
```

Here is the Python code I have tried but which fails to accomplish what I would like to do. My guess is that the "(" and "," characters are key regex items to do this. The code inside the loop works on individual string examples but, like most tutorials on the web, they seldom discuss how to loop through multiple rows of data and are therefore unhelpful at scaling up to real-world applications:

```
import re
# finds latitude:
for x in geotest:
    start = s.find('(') + 1
    end = s.find(',', start)
    s[start:end]
# finds longitude
for x in geotest:
    start = f.find(',') + 1
    end = f.find(')', start)
    f[start:end]
```

Thank you all for any guidance!

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me!

Here's the data:

```
geotest = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Riskfactor', 'Geolocation'], data=[['Smoking', (44.9033791, -122.9017427)], ['Alcohol', (38.84054, -97.6097)]])
print(geotest)
```

print result:

```
    Riskfactor     Geolocation
0    Smoking       (44.9033791, -122.9017427)
1    Alcohol       (38.84054, -97.6097)
```

Here's the solution to separate latitude and longitude info:

```
geotest['Latitude'] = geotest.apply(lambda row: row['Geolocation'][0], axis=1)
geotest['Longitude'] = geotest.apply(lambda row: row['Geolocation'][1], axis=1)
print(geotest)
```

Final result:

```
 Riskfactor    Geolocation                 Latitude    Longitude
0    Smoking   (44.9033791, -122.9017427)  44.903379   -122.901743
1    Alcohol   (38.84054, -97.6097)        38.840540   -97.609700
```

EDIT:

If your 'Geolocation' column is entirely a string, you my use this code:

```
geotest['Latitude'] = geotest.apply(lambda row: row['Geolocation'].split(',')[0].replace('(', ''), axis=1)
geotest['Longitude'] = geotest.apply(lambda row: row['Geolocation'].split(',')[1].replace(')',''), axis=1)
print(geotest)
```

The output will be the same as you can see:

```
Riskfactor      Geolocation                 Latitude      Longitude
0    Smoking    (44.9033791, -122.9017427)  44.9033791    -122.9017427
1    Alcohol    (38.84054, -97.6097)        38.84054      -97.6097
```

Comment: thanks so much for throwing an idea on the table!  For some reason, when I attempt to run in on my data set, I get a "(" in the appended Latitude column and a "4" in the appended Longitude column (both for row 1).  I do not get the entire number as you're getting.  Is there any add'l code you have that did that?

Comment: I think I found why your code is not working on my dataset as it does on your example.  If I replicate your example, but with single quotes around the lat/long text, I end up reproducing the results I just describe in my comment above.  So for example, your code with with single quotes:

geotest = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Riskfactor', 'Geolocation'], data=[['Smoking', '(44.9033791, -122.9017427)'], ['Alcohol', '(38.84054, -97.6097)']])

I think there is a distinct difference in the data type of your example vs. my data column.

Comment: I think that the first row of your 'GeoLocation' column is a String, thats why you're getting a "(" for [0] (first position) and a "4" for [1] (second position).

Comment: You're correct, I believe.  The data is coming straight out of a csv file and in the GeoLocation column (for row 1) contains the following string (parentheses are around the numbers):

(44.44.9033791, -122.9017427)

Any suggestions on how to correct for that?

Comment: If you can't change the first row of the csv file to match the other row, i think you should try to use string manupulation only in the first row, using commands  split() and replace() commands to remove unwanted characters. That's what came to mind first, if i think of something else i'll get back here. And if you find a another solution i'll be glad to hear

Answer (score 0):

I think that the simplest way to do this is to use the following line of code:

```
df[['Latitude', 'Longitude']] = df['GeoLocation'].str.strip('( )').str.split(',', expand=True)
```

Assuming that your existing dataframe is named `df`, the left side of the expression creates two new columns called `Latitude` and `Longitude`.  These new columns get populated with the current values stored in the *GeoLocation* field after unwanted characters are removed (or stripped) and split based on a comma delimiter.

Since coordinate pairs could be given as two values separated by a comma alone or by a comma followed by variable number of spaces, I included a space in the characters to be stripped prior to the split operation.